# Setting paragraph indentation to zero in LyX

Tags: lyx, indentation, paragraphs, parindent, tufte-book

In Tufte-Book class in LyX, putting `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` in the preamble does not work. How to properly set the paragraph indentation and paragraph break?

Comment: You try `\setlength{\parindent}{0em}` instead of `\setlength\parindent{0pt}`.

Comment: @Sebastiano, that should not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tufte-book` use the package `ragged2e` to change the text alignment.

By default, `tufte-book` change the text alignment to be `\RaggedRight`, with this settings the paragraph indent is stored in the length `\RaggedRightParindent`, thus you should write in your document's preamble `\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{0pt}`.

If you use the option `justified`, then the text alignment will be `\justifying`, and the paragraph indent will be stored inside the length `\JustifyingParindent`, thus in this case you should write in the preamble `\setlength{\JustifyingParindent}{0pt}`.

Comment: Thank you so very much!